# How can I Selecting Kendo Drop Down using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, kendo-ui

I have the following HTML:

```html
<table class="w98">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="p-controlSetLabel">
<td class="editor-field">
**<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="width: 165px;" title="" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="VatRateId_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="304dd433-4a68-458b-a6d6-03b72335f1cb">**
<span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-input" unselectable="on">Standard - Standard</span>
<span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">select</span>
</span>
</span>
<input id="VatRateId" class="k-valid" type="text" value="d20b" style="width: 165px; display: none;" name="VatRateId" data-val-required="Please select a VAT Rate." data-val="true" data-role="dropdownlist">
```

The `input id="VatRateId"` is hidden, so I can't access it.

My current solution is the following:
`var allDropDownFields = FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@class='k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default']")`   -- This will return a list of all drop down fields

Then I loop each one of them to find the correct drop down field I want.

Is there a better way of finding the element without getting a list, I tried the following:

```
FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default'and @aria-owns = 'VatRateId_listbox']")
```

and the above code is not work.

HTML code is as below:-

```
<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="width: 165px;" title="" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="VatRateId_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="304dd433-4a68-458b-a6d6-03b72335f1cb">* <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on"> <span class="k-input" unselectable="on">Standard - Standard</span>
```

Any better suggestion?

Comment: what exactly you want to return?

Comment: Why not just search by id?

Comment: @ Dmytro Pastovenskyi:  I want to return the following element: *<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="width: 165px;" title="" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="VatRateId_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="304dd433-4a68-458b-a6d6-03b72335f1cb">**
<span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-input" unselectable="on">Standard - Standard</span>

Comment: But unfortunately there are at least 5 elements on the page with the tag:span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style   -- that's why I am using a list

Comment: @Richard: I can't use the Id as I said before Kendo has hidden the ID, so if I use it I get 'Element not visible on the page' error. I wonder if there is a way to return the specific element above without returning all element matching <span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header"  tag

Comment: I'd missed the selenium bit: there are solutions to this: search for "Kendo DropDown Selenium" for [answers](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/5466/14755).